# A "constant" in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Say I have 2 columns:  (this is extremely simplified)

- Data = a number
- Result = Data * 1.2

I can put B2 = A2*1.2, then drag and drop B2 down...
[image] 
and it fills all the other cells, which is perfect.
[image]

But can I put this multiplier (`1.2`) somewhere as a "constant"? (for clarity and being easily editable)

Say I put it in E1, and set B2 = A2*E1.
Now I can't drag and drop anymore (because E1 becomes E2 E3 and so on)
[image]
In this example, is there a way to make E1 stay as you drag it down?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

## Short answer

Use an absolute cell reference or a named range

## Explanation

Instead of E1, which is a relative cell reference, use $E$1 which is an absolute cell reference.

An alternative is to to assign a name to the cell E1, let say, "constant"

In the first case the formula will be

```
=A2*$E$1
```

In the second case

```
=A2*constant
```

## References

- [Spreadsheet - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet)
- [Name a range of cells - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

I understand that you are asking for *"A “constant” in Google spreadsheet?"* and later on a *"drag down"* solution.

You can use the accepted answer, OR ...
*Instead of having to drag down (increasing the number of formulas)*

## **Use a single formula in `B2`**

```
=ArrayFormula(A2:A6*E1)
```

[image]

You can even use it for future entries or now blank cells.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A11<>"",A2:A11*E1,""))
```

[image]

### How the formula works

The `ArrayFormula` will apply the calculation `cell*E1` in every single row, `IF` the cell is not empty/blank `""`.
`IF` it is a blank cell it will return a blank cell `""`.

**Functions used:**

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: A superb solution for working with large datasets where dragging down would be infeasible (and where empty cells prevent auto-fill)!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this in your formula?

Cell B2 type

```
 =A2*$E$1
```

Then there is no need to drag it down on column E, it will all follow E1.
I believe this solves the problem.

If you really want to drag it down, then why not just put Cell E2

```
=E1
```

So that even when you drag, the value will remain 1.2